# Reload nginx from another Docker container

Tags: nginx, docker

We have two Docker containers:

- nginx
- consul-template

with a shared volume for nginx.conf.

The challenge is that when consul-template updates nginx.conf, it needs to signal nginx to reload. I cannot figure out a way (the right way?) to make this kind of interprocess call between containers... how to call `nginx reload` in the context of the nginx container, from a sibling container?

Answer (score 1):

I would run consul-template on the same server as nginx as a local process. May I know what impediments you have in running them together? Consul template is just a utility, not an application to warrant its own container. You will be chasing tails now since now you have to discover where's your nginx.

Comment: Introducing something like supervisord to run them both is an added layer of utility & abstraction. Not the end of the world.